# Intellij plugin for call stack graph

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea

Is there a plugin that would enable viewing debugger call stack graph. There is of course stack view but in big project it sometimes becomse very confusing (sometimes there are loops etc.) . What I would like to get is a graph of method invokations with additional information like values which they returned. I might try writing a plugin for this if no such thing exists.